# Can Alchemists Experimental elixirs be combined to generate a roll on the potion miscibility table in the DMG?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, class-feature, artificer

DMG p140 has a potion miscibility table. Artificer subclass Alchemist creates Experimental Elixirs.  Can these elixirs be combined for a roll on the aforementioned table?

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: It does indeed.

Comment: Good enough for a green check?

Comment: Yessir. It is indeed.

Comment: Anyway, I'm glad you've returned to the stack with more questions. While you're here, it would be great if you could back to some of your older questions and mark those answers which have solved your problems with the green check (this one included) to let those users know they have helped you.

Comment: I had no idea that was for me to do! Thank you!

Comment: Ah, yes! When a user solves your problem, you will see a check mark that you can click on to let them (and everyone else know) that that particular answer was the most helpful in solving your problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### [*Variant: Mixing Potions*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/treasure#Potions) is already an optional rule, so it is entirely up to the DM.

It is already up to the DM to decide if they want the Potion Miscibility table to apply to mixing potions. The artificer's elixirs seem to behave very similarly to potions, so a DM could reasonably rule that Potion Miscibility applies to the elixirs as well *if they have already decided to use these optional rules for traditional potions*.

Answer (score 6):

## Yes, if the optional rule is used.

The rules for mixing potions is a variant rule that a DM has the option to use if they want. The optional rules state:

> A character might drink one potion while still under the effects of another, or pour several potions into a single container. The strange ingredients used in creating potions
> can result in unpredictable interactions. When a character mixes two potions together, you can roll on the Potion Miscibility table. If more than two are combined, roll again for each subsequent potion, combining the results.

This is a general rule for combining potions and does not specify any limitation with regard to where the potions come from or how they were made. In fact, the item doesn't even have to be a "potion." The last effect reads:

> For example, a *potion of healing* might increase the drinker's hit point maximum by 4, or *oil of etherealness* might permanently trap the user in the Ethereal Plane.

A page earlier (139), the rules state:

> Different kinds of magical liquids are grouped in the category of potions: brews made from enchanted herbs, water from magical fountains or sacred springs, and oils that are applied to a creature or an object. Most potions consist of one ounce of liquid.

In other words, "Potion" is a catchall term for a "consumable magic item" as the book calls them. Further underlining this is the fact that the variant rules use *oil of etherealness* as an example of something that could have a new effect when mixed.

This makes it clear that the variant rules are intended to work with a wider array of magical brews than just things strictly called "potions." To wit: oils, elixirs, etc.

Absent some sort of rule stating that the experimental elixirs created by the Artificer somehow do not qualify as belonging to this broad "potion" category, they do since they are perfectly described by it.

Thus, it is up to the DM to decide if the rule is to be used, so check with them.

Comment: Is there a legitimate way the dm could veto the using of Alchemists elixirs for the optional potion miscability table, as the items generated are in no way stable beyond a long rest?

Comment: @Vitto The DM has final say in all matters. S/he can veto whatever they want and it would be legitimate :)

Comment: they are not technically potions

Comment: @thedragon thats what i think, too, as theyre fueled by spell slots, are impermanent, and, well, arent magic items from the dmg

Comment: @The As I point out in my answer, the example provided by the miscible "potion" rules *themselves* use an oil as an example of something that can be mixed. I think it's a mistake to look at the word "potion" in the title and ignore the fact that the full text doesn't limit the rules to only items called "potions."

Comment: @vit Why does it matter if the elixirs are made using spell slots, are impermanent? None of these disqualify them from being classified as potions according to the description.

Comment: @rykara because my pc wants to spam potion mixing on the 1% chance of getting a perma boon

Comment: @vit If your player wants to gamble with his/her gut like that, they are going to expend all their elixirs pursuing long odds. And if they *do* hit that discovery and "some harmful effects could result" as well. Seems like a good way to balance things to me. Frankly, as a DM, I'd welcome this kind of mad scientist play. It's true to the archetype.

Comment: It also might be of note, that the GM should roll *secretly* on the Potion Miscibility table, if they're using it, and "Unless the effects are immediately obvious, reveal them only when they become evident." If an alchemist is trying to mix elixirs, only the 01 table result seems like it would be immediately apparent without drinking it, and with a %1 chance of a permanent result and a %7 chance of being poisonous with another %7 of nothing happening it seems like long odds of being worth the risk.